# How do I get routes to work with AngularDart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

This is my code,

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

class AppModule extends Module {

  AppModule(){
    type(AppController);
    type(LoginController);
    type(RouteInitializer, implementedBy: AppRouter);
  }

}

class AppRouter implements RouteInitializer {

  init(Router router, ViewFactory view) {
   router.root
    ..addRoute(
      name: 'login',
      path: '/login',
      enter: view('app/views/login.tpl.html'))
    ..addRoute(
       defaultRoute: true,
       name: 'index',
       enter: view('app/views/index.tpl.html'));
  }

}

@NgController(selector: '[app-ctrl]', publishAs: 'ctrl')
class AppController {

}

@NgController(selector: '[login-ctrl]', publishAs: 'ctrl')
class LoginController {

  Http _http;
  String works = 'Works.';

  LoginController(this._http);

}
```

No routes are working, clicking on a '#/login' link does not change the url or the view.

Log says

```
clicked /app/web/index.html#/login
route /app/web/index.html [Route: null]
route  [Route: index]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There might be a couple of problems with this code. From what I can see the most likely problem is that the routing is using pushState. When you use pushState you don't manipulate the url using a hash. For more information on that see:
[Manipulating Browser History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Angular will use push state when a browser supports it.

```dart
bind(NgRoutingUsePushState, toValue: new NgRoutingUsePushState.value(false));
```

Giving you are module of:

```dart
class AppModule extends Module {

  AppModule(){
    bind(AppController);
    bind(LoginController);
    bind(RouteInitializer, implementedBy: AppRouter);
    bind(NgRoutingUsePushState, toValue: new NgRoutingUsePushState.value(false));
  }
}
```

Other possible problems include:

- Not having an ng-view directive
- Not setting the ng-bind-route in app/views/login.tpl.html, and app/views/index.tpl.html

When I made all these changes your code worked correctly for me when navigating to #/login

Comment: I don't understand your snippet of code. What factory and in what context are you adding that code?

Comment: The factory is added to the module. It turns off using pushState for Html5 browsers.

Comment: Or you can use value binding:
value(NgRoutingUsePushState, new NgRoutingUsePushState.value(false));

Comment: How do you set the `ng-bind-route`

Comment: `ng-bind-route` seems to be no longer needed: http://blog.angulardart.org/2013/11/angulardart-v091.html