# AngularDart NgRoutingUsePushState does not change route

Tags: routes, dart, angular-dart

I must have `bind(NgRoutingUsePushState, toValue: new NgRoutingUsePushState.value(false));` in order for my router to work. This is causing issues with my ability to implement Google Analytics, Disqus and Twitter on specific pages, as it seems as though since it isn't a page load it doesn't register as a new page so everything is lumped under index.html which is not going to work for me.

My dependencies are:

```
dependencies:
  browser: any
  angular: 0.14.0
```

am I missing anything? I really would like separate Disqus threads on my site instead of one big one

Comment: What do you mean by 'not work' when using PushState?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upon further diagnosis it seems the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030527/how-do-i-get-routes-to-work-with-angulardart?rq=1) tells me pushState can't be used when using fragments. Closing question.